# how to change bootstrap columns while width is 320

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:100px;text-align:center;">
    <div class="col-md-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <span>TEXT</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <span>TEXT1</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <span>TEXT2</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code produces 3 spans in one line horizontally, like this:

```
TEXT     TEXT1     TEXT2
```

I want to do responsive code when the view width is 320px. I want the spans to be arranged vertically:

```
TEXT
TEXT1
TEXT2
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the width at different screen sizes. You have already specified `md` width of the column. 
If you want the column to use full width on extra small screens(<320px) you have to add the class `col-xs-12`.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <span>TEXT</span></a>
</div>
```

In the above example the div will use full width on extra small screen, half width on small screens and 25% width(as you already had) on medium screen size(and bigger).

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
        if (window.width() <= 322) {
          
            $('#a').addClass('col-xs-12').removeClass('col-md-3');
            $('#b').addClass('col-xs-12').removeClass('col-md-4');
           

        }
    });
i have applied this code bt does not work

Comment: id there need to specify id lyk i hd given a and b to apply this code

Comment: @shrutni: Why would you remove the class? This is not the way to go. Specify behaviour by applying the neccessary bootstrap classes.

Comment: i am not getting still

Comment: What are you not "getting"? Have a look at this: http://www.bootply.com/FGNpD2KUGH